# Induction Proof - Computation Theory

Tags: proof-writing, induction

For my theory of computation class, we are supposed to do some review/practice problems to work off the rust and make sure we are ready for the course. Some of the problems are induction proofs. I did this at one time, but apparently it has completely escaped me. I've watched a couple tutorials, but still can't do problem 'a'. If anyone can walk me through the first problem I'm pretty sure I could figure out the second one on my own. Any help would be appreciated!

a. $\displaystyle \forall n>0\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)$.

b. $\forall n>0 (n!\ge 2^{n-1})$. Recall that $0!=1$ and $\forall n>0(n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 1)$.

Comment: You should try to make the question more specific. Also, you should describe what you have tried, so people can write answers at the correct level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic induction process goes like this:

1. Show that the base case is true
2. Assume it is true for some $n=k$
3. Show that this implies that it is also true for $n=k+1$

1. So, in your problem (a), we first show that the base case satisfies the equationis true. For $n=1$ we have:
   $\large\sum_{i=1}^{1}i^2=1^2=1\tag{1}$
   and:
   $\large\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=\frac{1(1+1)(2+1)}{6}=\frac{6}{6}=1\tag{2}$
   Since (1) and (2) match, we have shown the base case to be true.
2. Now we assume it is true for some $n=k$ to get:
   $\large\sum_{i=1}^{k}i^2=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}\tag{3}$
3. Finally we use this to prove that it must therefore also be true for $n=k+1$:
   $\large\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i^2=(\sum_{i=1}^{k}i^2)+(k+1)^2$
   $\large=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}+(k+1)^2$ (using result (3))
   $\large=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)+6(k+1)^2}{6}$
   $\large=\frac{(k+1)(k(2k+1)+6(k+1))}{6}$
   $\large=\frac{(k+1)(2k^2+k+6k+6)}{6}$
   $\large=\frac{(k+1)(2k^2+7k+6)}{6}$
   $\large=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}$
   $\large=\frac{(k+1)((k+1)+1)(2(k+1)+1)}{6}$

Hence we have proved the case for $n=k+1$. This completes prof by induction.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but how did you get result 3?

Comment: result 3 is a consequence of the 2nd step in the induction proof where you assume the item you are trying to prove is valid for some value of $n$, say $n=k$

Comment: [This](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/mathematical-induction.html) might help you in understanding the process of mathematical induction better.